# Finding the value of function defined as the limit of multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have a function

$f(x,y) = \frac{\cos{x}-\cos{y}}{2(x^2+y^2)}$

and we define

$F(x) := \lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y)$

How would I go about finding $F(0)$?

I am unclear whether to plug the value in first, and then take the limit, eg.

$F(0) = \lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y) = \frac{1}{4}$

or take the limit first, and then plug in the value.

$F(x) = \lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y) = \frac{\cos{x}-1}{2(x)^2} $

$F(0) = \frac{\cos{0}-1}{2(0)^2} $

In this case, the function is undefined.

I have attempted to compute the value in Maple, and I've gotten the following

```
f := (x, y) -> (cos(x) - cos(y))/(2*y^2 + 2*x^2)
F := x -> limit(f(x, y), y = 0)
F(0) = 1/4
```

This would suggest the first approach being correct, but I am still unsure whether this is actually true and why it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first solution is definitely the most intuitive. It follows the definition
$$F(x)=\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)\implies F(0)=\lim_{y\to0}f(0,y)$$
Taking the limit of $\frac{\cos{x}-1}{2x^2}$ implies nothing else than the fact that the function is discontinuous, as $F(0)=\frac{1}{4}$ and the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos{x}-1}{2x^2}=-\frac{1}{4}$.

Thus, $F$ is defined at $x=0$, although $\frac{\cos{x}-1}{2x^2}$ is not. This is due to the function being defined as a limit, not the result of the limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the limit first, you should write :

For $x\ne 0,$

$$F(x)=\frac{(\cos(x)-1)}{2x^2}$$

$F$ is not defined at $x=0$ but it has a limit, which is

$-\frac 14.$

This example proves that, in general

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\lim_{y\to 0}f(x,y))\ne \lim_{y\to 0}(\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,y))$$
with $$f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$F(0) := \lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y)$$

that is

$$\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\cos{0}-\cos{y}}{2(0^2+y^2)}=\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{1-\cos y}{2y^2}=\frac14$$